# Can't create responsive horizontal layout for email sign-up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a responsive horizontal layout for an email sign-up form which should look like the image below (image taken at browser width 1024px):

[image: email sign-up form layout]

The problem I keep having is that the input button keeps overlapping with the location select field on browser resizing, and the dimensions of the email address input field cannot be modified at all.

I have tried a number of things including setting the widths of the elements individually as percentages and setting to `display:inline-block`.

I've also tried setting the parent elements to `display:table` and the child elements to `display: table-cell`, but this hasn't worked either.

As I am working on top of quite a few layers of legacy code this has proven to be exceptionally difficult - divs nested several levels down and numerous higher level "clearfix" divs. I am not sure how far the latter is influencing things.

Unfortunately the html markup is rather dense in the js fiddle I've created, but I wanted to show as much as possible of the relevant area as shown in Chrome inspector.

I have grabbed the most relevant html markup and css using a chrome plugin and imported in js fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/md6hg36y/1/)

The js fiddle represents my latest attempt (of many) using the table display properties for the layout - as in the original shown in the image which I cannot recreate.

Comment: Okay, try then. All the best.

Comment: what u need exactly from us?

Comment: Sorry @PraveenKumar and Vikash - I posted the question by mistake earlier - the above is my full question

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.  Try making a jsfiddle as well.

Comment: @Lowkase the js fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/md6hg36y/1/ (as in my original question)